# why does C++ regex only find a part of what javascript regex find in a string?

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I need to use regex in my code, but it doesn't work as it should.
I would like to search for `Test.list.everything` in a file I read line per line, but it only gets `everything`. I shortened my code to make my problem clear. In different regex test programs my expression works correctly as you can see it in this test program: http://regex101.com/r/iR1cH1.

The input I used there is

```
summer1969 2014-03-07 Test.list.everything.1234 123.4.4.34 moreCode
```

and the regex `(([a-zA-Z]+\.{0,1})+)\.[0-9]+`.

It doesn't work correctly either if I used `std::tr1::regex` instead of `std::regex`.
I don't know the difference between this two expressions, is there any?

What is the difference between C++ and the other programs I used? How can I tell C++ regex to behave like other ones?

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string output = "summer1969 2014-03-07 Test.list.everything.1234 123.4.4.34 moreCode";
    std::cmatch result;
    std::regex rx ("(([a-zA-Z]+\\.{0,1})+)\\.[0-9]+");
    std::regex_search(output.c_str(), result, rx);
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << ". " << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
0. everything.1234
1. everything
2. everything.
```

Comment: Which compiler? `std::regex` may not be fully implemented in some.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Clang 3.4: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e8b6baf83f79f817

Comment: I use the Visual Studio 2010 C++ Compiler.

Comment: Visual Studio's implementation is probably non-conformant.

Comment: So what should I use instead of ´std::regex´?

Comment: You can use `boost::regex`

Comment: I tried with VS2013 and the output is `0. Test.list.everything.1234` `1. Test.list.everything` `2. g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Visual C++ 2010. If you want to capture the text followed by dot and number, then you can use the following regex:

```
"[a-zA-Z\\.]+(?=\\.\\d+)"
```

It works fine.